# scala span method is not behaving as expected

Tags: scala, list

I have this:

```
List('a','a', 'a', 'b')
```

and i want to obtain this:

```
List(List('a','a', 'a'), List('b'))
```

Here is my code:

```
def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: xs1 =>  val y = xs1.head
    println("x is " + x)
    println("y is " + y)
    val (head,tail) = xs1 span ( x => x.equals(xs1.head))
    println("head is " + head)
    println("tail is " + tail)
   (x :: head) ::  pack(tail)
}

pack(List('a','a', 'a', 'b'))
```

which returns this:

```
x is a
y is a
head is List(a, a)
tail is List(b)

java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
```

question:

1. why my head is not List(a,a,a) and tail is not just List(b)
2. why does it return an error for empty list and not a Nil?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your questions:

1. The `case x :: xs1` statement sets `x` to the head of `xs` and `xs1` to its tail. I think you might have wanted your `span` statement to be `xs1 span(_ == x)`: take elements from `xs1` - the tail - that match the first element `x` of `xs`. Because you applied `span` to `xs1`, instead of `xs`, you missed the first element. (You do prefix the head with that value afterwards, though.) However, your `span` predicate looks at the head of `xs1`, instead of `x`, leading to the error - see answer (2). (BTW, you have two different `x` variables in your `pack` function, making matters a little more confusing, which is why I anonymized the `span` predicate argument.)
2. It actually does return `Nil` for an empty list. You get an error when `xs` has only one element, meaning that its tail, `xs1` is empty. Looking at the `head` of an empty list gives that error.

If you want separate lists of identical elements that appear consecutively, then `span` will do that for you: it puts elements that pass the predicate (characters that are the same as the first character) into its first returned list; but as soon as the predicate fails for an element, that element and everything that follows is put in the second list. So if you were expecting that, you were right...

For example (in a *Scala REPL* sessions):

```scala
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val xs = List('a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
xs: List[Char] = List(a, a, a, b)

scala> xs.span(_ == 'a')
res0: (List[Char], List[Char]) = (List(a, a, a),List(b))
```

I'd rewrite your `pack` function like this, which is simpler and avoids some of the pitfalls in your original version (namely, removing the head of the `xs` list, then using `span` on its tail, with the wrong target character, then trying to reconstruct the lists by re-prefixing the original head):

```scala
scala> def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
     !
     !   // If xs is empty, return Nil.
     !   case Nil => Nil
     !
     !   // Otherwise, the list is non-empty, so just process it.
     !   case _ => {
     !     val (head, tail) = xs.span(_ == xs.head)
     !
     !     // Prefix head to packed tail.
     !     head :: pack(tail)
     !   }
     ! }
pack: [T](xs: List[T])List[List[T]]

scala> pack(xs)
res1: List[List[Char]] = List(List(a, a, a), List(b))
```

However, if the elements are mixed up, then you may not like the result:

```scala
scala> val mixed = List('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a')
mixed: List[Char] = List(a, a, b, c, a, a, b, a)

scala> pack(mixed)
res2: List[List[Char]] = List(List(a, a), List(b), List(c), List(a, a), List(b), List(a))
```

That's because `span` stops looking at elements when the predicate fails. If you want to separate the `'a'`, `'b'` & `'c'` elements into separate lists, then you need `partition` instead of `span`: everything that passes the predicate goes into the first list; everything that fails into the second. Your `pack` function then becomes:

```scala
scala> def pack2[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
     !
     !   // If xs is empty, return Nil.
     !   case Nil => Nil
     !
     !   // Otherwise, the list is non-empty, so just process it.
     !   case _ => {
     !     val (head, tail) = xs.partition(_ == xs.head)
     !
     !     // Prefix head to packed tail.
     !     head :: pack2(tail)
     !   }
     ! }
pack2: [T](xs: List[T])List[List[T]]

scala> pack2(xs)
res3: List[List[Char]] = List(List(a, a, a), List(b))

scala> pack2(mixed)
res4: List[List[Char]] = List(List(a, a, a, a, a), List(b, b), List(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

`x :: xs` is a patterns for matching the head (first element) and tail (rest) of a list. If a list has 1 element then tail will be Nil but you're calling `.head` on that tail causing the error. I think one way of doing what you want would be:

```
  def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case x :: xs1 =>
          val (prefix, rest) = xs1 span (_.equals(x))
          (x :: prefix) :: pack(rest)
  }
```

For many different elements that might not be the best way of doing this though.